# Renaming multiple variables at once in R

Tags: r, rename, gsub

I have multiple variables in my environment whose names end in either '.xlsx' or '.csv' What is an easy way to remove these extensions from their names without creating new variables and deleting the old ones.

I know that this could be solved previously by removing the extensions from the names while loading each file, but that is not the kind of solution I am looking for.

I have tried using combinations of `gsub` and `names` without any success.

Any help?

Comment: YOu meant object names or files

Comment: object names, as if some .csv file had already been loaded to R

Comment: Perhaps `dirname(chartr(".", "/", x))`. Can you share a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `file_path_sans_ext`

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext(c('file.csv', '.xlsx'))
```

If they are object names

```
nm <- ls(pattern = '\\.(csv|xlsx)$')
nm1 <- tool::file_path_sans_ext(nm)
list2env(setNames(mget(nm), nm1), .GlobalEnv)
rm(list = nm)
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood. when I run ```tool::file_path_sans_ext(ls())``` all I get is the new list of names. How can assign these names to my original objects?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito Please check my upddate

Answer (score 0):

This is not right way to do it, but it should work. It will take all objects `ls` with xlsx in name and remove with `gsub` the ".xsls" and remove `rm` the original object. Similarly it can be done for csv.

```
   for(i in grep("xlsx",ls(), value=T)){
    assign(gsub("\\.xlsx","",i), eval(i))
    rm(eval(i))
   }
```